# How to grep for a string with spaces in a list of given files?

Tags: bash, unix, grep, xargs

If the search string has space, it is being treated as 2 separate strings instead of just one. How can I make the search string be treated as a single value? Using xargs to pass the files that need to be searched to grep works fine.

Here is findInFiles.sh script

```
SEARCH_STR=$1
SEARCH_FILES=$2
# This line return results with search for individual strings
cat $SEARCH_FILES | xargs grep $SEARCH_STR
# This line return no results, while it works fine on command line
cat $SEARCH_FILES | xargs grep "$SEARCH_STR"
```

This is how the script is executed

```
./findInFiles.sh "go green" /tmp/search_files.out

/tmp/search_files.out has:
    src/file1.py
    src/file2.py
    src/file3.py
```

Again 'cat $SEARCH_FILES | xargs grep $SEARCH_STR' in the script interprets "go green" as 2 separate words while 'cat $SEARCH_FILES | xargs grep "$SEARCH_STR"' works on command line but not in script i.e produces no results.

---

SOLVED: The script actually works with 'cat $SEARCH_FILES | xargs grep "$SEARCH_STR"'. I've been trying it with wrong input. Sorry!

Comment: `cat $SEARCH_FILES | xargs grep "$SEARCH_STR"`

Comment: Tried that variation already, works when I try it in command line but  not in script. Not sure why.

Comment: try `cat $SEARCH_FILES | xargs grep "${SEARCH_STR}"`

Comment: No change. Same results as `cat $SEARCH_FILES | xargs grep "$SEARCH_STR"`. For some reason it is not recognizing the qutoes. Have tried escaping the quotes with no luck

Comment: @SriniK Are you actually using bash (i.e. does top say something like `#!/bin/bash`). Also run your script with `bash -x findInFiles.sh` for more details of what's going on. Also also, quote both your variables, not just one (shouldn't matter for the particular input, but no reason not to unless you explicitly want word splitting)

Comment: oops! the script is right, but I'm using the wrong search string. Thanks for bash -x, that saved my day.

Comment: why not ` grep "$SEARCH_STR" $(cat $SEARCH_FILES)`

Answer (score -1):

```
try like
SEARCH_STR="$1"
SEARCH_FILES=$2
# This line return results with search for individual strings
cat $SEARCH_FILES | grep "$SEARCH_STR"
```

Comment: We need to use xargs, can't pipe files directly to grep.

Comment: I think Kuldeep expected that $SEARCH_FILES was a list of files, not a file with a list. His soltution is a bit like `cat $(cat $SEARCH_FILES) | grep "$SEARCH_STR"`